# Is there a way to tell windows phone upload Camera Roll pictures to SkyDrive via wifi only?

Tags: upload, windows-phone, onedrive

I'm a newbie on Windows Phone, I spent time on iOS and Android before and use the instant upload feature as well.

I found that on the Windows Phone, there's an option to upload Camera Roll pictures to SkyDrive which is as similar as Photo Stream or Google+ instant update did. But the problem is there is no option to tell it just upload via WiFi only, not the data plan (GRPS/EDGE/3G).

Because sometimes I capture picture while the 3G is on and do not want my phone upload it, that will eat up my data. I only have 400 MB of high-speed bandwidth, thus I'm don't want a ton of data transferred via cellular data connection.

So how can I set that feature just works on WiFi only, or prevent it upload via 3G?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Disable the data connection of the `Cellular` provider before performing the upload by doing the following:

- Go to `Settings`
- Go to `Cellular`
- Set `Data Connection` to `Off`

Comment: Seeming that you misunderstand me. I don't want the phone upload my pictures until it find a Wifi connection. I may be on travel, take some picture, then turn cellular data on to access facebook, for example, then it use my data plan for instant upload.

Comment: There is a [registry key](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/skydrive-wlsecurity/gporegistry-skydrive-control/5febc70f-fb2d-4405-9334-cd9013f6ac74). It may or may not be available, depending on the phone and the availability of a registry editor.

Comment: I don't know what are you talking about.

Comment: In general: I am referring to the [Windows registry](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-registry). Specificially: I am referring to the [Windows Embedded Compact registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj584847.aspx)